# Initialize JQuery plugin from data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

You can initialize a bootstrap dropdown without any javascript. You can also manually initialize it.

I created a JQuery plugin and I merge all of my defaults and and options with `$.extends`.

```
var settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options, $self.data());
```

My plugin get's initialized like any normal plugin.

```
$('ul.dropdown.users-list').awesomeplugin({/* ... */});
```

What would be the right method for having it initialize automatically, but also not get duplicated if it is initialized manually, in the same way that a bootstrap dropdown works?

For example I understand that I could do something like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('[data-myawesomeplugin]').each(function(){
     $(this).myawesomeplugin();
 });
});
```

But if someone decided to initialize manually, wouldn't initialization happen twice?

Comment: That's easy, unless it's supposed to work with dynamically inserted elements that are added some time in the future. If not, you just search for elements with a certain data attribute, and run the plugin on those elements.

Comment: @adeneo but if you then decided to do it manually for once to specify some option, wouldn't you manually initializing the plugin also then get it's own initialization from the data attributes? Therefore it would get initialized twice?

Comment: Just add a class to the elements that have been initialized in your plugin, or something similar, and then check for that in the plugin, that's the usual way to avoid double initialisation

Answer (score 0):

After the page loads ( or any other required dependency loads ), you can select all required elements (using jquery selectors) and initialize them.
Moreover add some kind of object pool which stores all initialized objects.
During initialization of object you can check if that object was already initialized, if so you just return that object and don't create any new object. Identification of unique objects and fetching old ones is completely based on your use case.